# How can I fix this serious git clone error?

Tags: git, github

I tried the following:

```
E:\Workspace\Blockchain>git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template.git
Cloning into 'substrate-node-template'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2185, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (91/91), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Receiving objects: 94%(2062/2185), 3.18 MiB | 9.00 KiB/s
```

...

After a 20 minute delay at 94%, the result is:

```
E:\Workspace\Blockchain>git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template.git
Cloning into 'substrate-node-template'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2185, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (91/91), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
error: 6546 bytes of body are still expectediB | 11.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You might be able to simply run `git remote update` to synchronize your (partial) local respostory with the remote. If that doesn't work, I suspect you'll just have to try cloning it again.

Comment: perhaps a network issue on your side, just try to clone and it was done in less than 5s
also you can try to clone with `git@github.com:substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template.git`

Comment: Thank you for time and attention. So you mean that I have to download repository zip file and set remote address with local address?

Comment: No, basically, just try again. You most likely had a networking error the first time you tried.

Comment: I just tried your clone, and it stayed "stuck" at 94% for about 5 or 6 seconds, and then finished normally. So yes, there is a big file/blob being downloaded at that point, but not that big.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, is there any method to fix my problem if the networking error is the reason?